# How can I reuse this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've wrote a function which is working fine and all but when I try to reuse it on multiple html blocks with the same class, it breaks. I've tried to use the `.next()` and `.closest()` method but without results. Where do I apply these? The function is to recreate a `<select>` dropdown but by using a unordered list.

It is important that the classes and function stay the same as the list is generated by the CMS and can be multiple times a page, so having a solution where I change the code and call each function separate is not good..

**Demos**

[Dropdown works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/6mukW/1/) (function works fine on one unordered list)

[Dropdown breaks](http://jsfiddle.net/6mukW/2/) (when reusing function and html code)

Comment: I guess you need to change `$(".options").toggle();` to `$(this).next(".options").toggle();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be better.. Check out this fiddle

using `toggleClass()`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mukW/15/)

Comment: Oh great, that saves a lot of code, not even starting about comparing the logic of what I wrote. Thanks!

Comment: Stumbled upon a bug using this.. When I select a list item and click on the 'dropdown' again the list order defaults again and the first item is shown.. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: so you want last selected item first in list again when user click in it ?

Comment: Yes, is this possible with the append method?

Comment: I did this in the function I wrote by the .clone() method in an empty span but not sure if that is the best solution?

Answer (score 3):

Your script had a number of things that needed changing. [This should work](http://jsfiddle.net/6mukW/11/), as best as I could understand what you were trying to do.

Main point being this:

```
$(".cloned").click(function(){
    $('.options').toggle();
    e.preventDefault();                 
});
```

The `$('.options')` selector inside the handler selects **all** the elements with the `options` class, regardless of where you clicked in the document. That's why every dropdown was activating on a click.

You should only select the specific `.options` element for the click. There are many ways to do this, but this is what I did:

```
$(this).next('.options').toggle();
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your clear answer and solution. What I tried with this is to make a unordered list to behave as a <select>. When you select a list element in the list a next list pops up.. The first working demo is basically what it is but it is reused multiple times over the same page. Hope that makes sense..